# Autofac Not Intercepting Calls To Classes

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac

I can not get autofac to intercept the calls to my classes.
I have modified the Program.cs file such that it includes Autofac.
I have modified the Startup.cs file such that it includes ConfigureContainer.
When the method is called it bypasses the Intercept method within the Loggable attribute.  What is missing?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                          .UseKestrel()
                          .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddAutofac())
                          .UseStartup<Startup>().Build();
        host.Run();
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var helper = new StartupHelper();
        helper.Configure(builder, Configuration);
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOData();
        services.AddMvc()
                .AddControllersAsServices();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        var name = "OData";
        var prefix = "OData";
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

        builder.EntitySet<DistributorParent>("DistributorParents")
               .EntityType
               .HasKey(a => a.DistparKey);

        app.UseMvc(routebuilder =>
        {
            routebuilder.Select()
                        .Expand()
                        .Filter()
                        .OrderBy()
                        .MaxTop(null)
                        .Count();
            routebuilder.MapODataServiceRoute(name, prefix, builder.GetEdmModel());
        });
    }
}

public class StartupHelper
{
    public ContainerBuilder Configure(ContainerBuilder builder, IConfiguration configuration = null)
    {
        builder.Register(a => configuration);
        builder.Register(a => new Loggable());
        builder.RegisterType<DistributorParentBusiness>()
               .As<IBusiness<DistributorParent>>()
               .EnableInterfaceInterceptors()
               .InterceptedBy(typeof(Loggable));
        return builder;
    }
}


[Loggable]
public class DistributorParentBusiness : IBusiness<DistributorParent>
{
    private IConfiguration Configuration;
    private String Connection;

    public DistributorParentBusiness(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("CorpdbConnection");
    }

    public virtual DistributorParent Get(Int32 key)
    {
        var context = new CorpdbContext(Connection);
        var query = from a in context.DistributorParent
                    where a.DistparKey == key
                    select a;
        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<DistributorParent> Get()
    {
        var context = new CorpdbContext(Connection);
        var query = from a in context.DistributorParent
                    select a;
        return query;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot to unpack here and not 100% of the information required to do it. I'll give you some things to look at and one of them should help.

**You're using interface interceptors, so only interface methods will be intercepted.** I don't know what the `IBusiness<T>` interface looks like (part of the missing information) so I don't know which of the methods in `DistributorParentBusiness` is part of the interface. If you call a method that *isn't* in the interface, it won't get intercepted.

**`Loggable` looks like an attribute but needs to implement `IInterceptor`.** I don't know what `Loggable` looks like, but it must implement `IInterceptor` if you're using it to intercept. It does strike me as odd that it's an attribute at all; it doesn't seem to be doing anything as it's applied in attribute form.

[The Autofac docs have examples of setting up interface injection.](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html) If you use the `InterceptedBy(typeof(T))` then you don't use attributes. If you want to use attributes, it needs to be `[Intercept(typeof(Logger))]` and, if you use the attribute, you *don't* use `InterceptedBy(typeof(T))`. It's either/or, and the interceptor is never the attribute itself.

**Controllers are services but I don't know where `IBusiness<DistributorParent>` is getting used.** Again, missing info. If it's being injected into a controller it should work; I think it should even work if you don't add controllers-as-services.

**That route builder call where you count all the routes is weird.** No, this has nothing to do with the question, but... it's counting them and not using the value? What's... uh... what's going on there?

**What I would try is creating a unit-test level repro for yourself.** That is, create a tiny repro just in a unit test that you can step into. Make sure you're wiring up the interface interception correctly first. Make a super simple, basically empty `IBusiness<DistributorParent>` implementation; create a container that has the interface interception wired up on that; resolve `IBusiness<DistributorParent>` manually; set a breakpoint in the interceptor; call a method you expect to be intercepted and see if the breakpoint is hit. Or create an interceptor that always returns a fixed known value and use that in your test if breakpoints aren't getting hit - sometimes settings like "Just My Code" and so on can end up causing certain things to be skipped.

Point being, if none of the above things get you unwound, create a real minimum repro in a unit test form and make sure it works. Widen it up a little if it does - maybe you used some other interceptor in the repro and it works; try the actual `Loggable` interceptor. Does it still work? If not, maybe the problem's the interceptor. If so, keep widening scope. Eventually you'll either get the whole thing working or you'll find the spot that isn't working.

If you do get the whole thing working in a minimal repro, then it's possible the issue is something you don't realize. For example, is the code in the repro exactly the same as the code in the real system? What's different? Work up to making the repro code close to the real code and see when it stops working.

The minimum repro is really going to be your key here, though, I think.

**Recommendation for future questions** - when you create the code for the question, try to make it the simple, tiny repro that I described above for troubleshooting. Enough to show the problem (and possibly be compiled by someone who wants to try it out) but no more.

- Include all the class and interface definitions in play. `Loggable` and `IBusiness<T>`, for example.
- Remove stuff that isn't needed. The route configuration in the `app.UseMvc()` call isn't relevant, for example.
- Try to simplify indirection and complexity. The code from the `StartupHelper` could be inlined into the `ConfigureContainer` method to make this easier to read through and understand for folks answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was very silly.  I was manually creating the class and not using di.  Therefore the methods weren't getting intercepted.  Also, the original setup was trying to intercept the api controller and the methods weren't virtual.  Little config changes to inject IBusiness and voila, it worked...